# Special characters while flush the data to file over NFS shared mount

Tags: java

Our Application reads the XML file and writes the text file as output on the shared NFS file system. The RHEL version on which application runs in 7.6 and the NFS is with veritas Access version 7.2 and 7.4 (on both environment has the issue), and NFS server OS is RHEL 7.2 and RHEl 7.4 (on both environment has the issue)

Have checked the value being written to the file before writting actually to the file. The data retrieved is correct. Once after writing to the file, have got the special character. (Its not the same character all the time)

Is there anything can be suspected on Veritas or RHEL or JAVA? Please share if any troubleshooting procedures available.

Java API used to write the file is Printwriter

Have tried all the encodings which can ,match both NFS server abd RHEL client. 
Tried all the java encoding JVM parameteres
Tries all the file open close and flush mechanism.
Changes the JAVA api to FileOutPutStream and wrote the data by storing in StringBuilder.

Even after trying all the possible solutions. Still the issue persists.

Code :

```
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile, true), "ISO-8859-1");
        coldelimiter = "\t";
        rowdelimiter = "\n";

        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw));

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            final DataToWrite data = iterator.next();
            writer.write(data.getDataName());
            writer.write(coldelimiter);

            }
            writer.write(rowdelimiter);
            writer.flush();
```

Expected :

testSystem testSystem 1 14 1 managedSystem 1 1 1310 2019-04-10 01:00:00 2019-04-10 10 Alpha testSystem +0100 1 0 4 15 29201 15MIN 2019-04-10 00:00:00 2019 13

Actual :

testSystem testSystem 1 14 1 manag)edSystem 1 1 1310 2019-04-10 01:00:00 2019-04-10 10 Alpha testSystem +0100 1 0 4 15 29201 15MIN 2019-04-10 00:00:00 2019 13 `q

I expect new line [ \n ] at the end, but sometimes junk characters like `q,) etc are getting appended at random columns.

Comment: A better and more detailed description of what happens is needed. 90% of errors are in the code; so show some code too. Welcome.

Comment: Updated the necessary details. Please help

Answer (score 0):

That code looks okay, only `rowdelimiter` might theoretically be overwritten, but why then some random character.

You are appending, but should there be a bug, like an end-of-file char, after which is appended, then the linebreak still would show up.

If the data is not wrong, it could be the reading code. With a backtick+q it looks like data.

Noted:
- For special Windows-Latin-1 (and browser Latin-1 one might use the Windows-1252 i.o. ISO-8859-1.
- The line break on Linux is `"\n"`, on Windows "\r\n".

```
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile, true), "Windows-1252");
    final String coldelimiter = "\t";
    final String rowdelimiter = "\r\n";
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw));
```

Or with more closed, less error prone code:

```
final String coldelimiter = "\t";
final String rowdelimiter = "\r\n";
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
Path outPath = outFile.toPath(); // File outFile
Path outPath = Paths.get(outFile); // String outFile

try (BufferedWriter osw = Files.newBufferedWriter(outPath, charset,
            StandardOpenOptions.APPEND, StandardOpenOptions.CREATE);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(osw)) {

   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final DataToWrite data = iterator.next();
        writer.write(data.getDataName());
        writer.write(coldelimiter);
        ...
        writer.write(rowdelimiter);
        writer.flush();  
    }
} // Automatic close, also on exception
```